# write a code to find the number of words in a string using methods

Tags: java

I've been looking and I can't find anywhere how to write a word count using 3 methods. Here is what the code looks like so far. I'm lost on how to use the methods. I can do this without using different methods and just using one. Please help!!!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    if (s.length() > 0)
    {
        getInputString(s);
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR - string must not be empty.");
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        s = in.nextLine();
    }
    // Fill in the body with your code
}

// Given a Scanner, prompt the user for a String.  If the user enters an empty
// String, report an error message and ask for a non-empty String.  Return the
// String to the calling program.
private static String getInputString(String s) {
    int count = getWordCount();
    while (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (s.charAt(i) == " ")
        {
            count ++;
        }
    }
    getWordCount(count);
    // Fill in the body

    // NOTE: Do not declare a Scanner in the body of this method.
}


// Given a String return the number of words in the String.  A word is a sequence of 
// characters with no spaces.  Write this method so that the function call:
//      int count = getWordCount("The quick brown fox jumped");
// results in count having a value of 5.  You will call this method from the main method.
// For this assignment you may assume that
// words will be separated by exactly one space.
private static int getWordCount(String input) {
    // Fill in the body
}

}
```

EDIT:
I have changed the code to

```
private static String getInputString(String s) {
    String words = getWordCount(s);
    return words.length();
}


private static int getWordCount(String s) {
    return s.split(" ");
}
```

But I can't get the string convert to integer.

Comment: looks like you're using methods fine, what problem are you having with using methods?

Comment: It's ok to ask concrete questions here, but we're not gonna do your homework. Please be very clear in what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: `if (s.charAt(i) == " ")` will always be false as you're asking if a char is the same object as a String. `' '` would represent a space as a character

Comment: I was semi surprised `s.charAt(i) == " "` even compiles.  Then i remembered autoboxing, and that this basically acts like `Character.valueOf(s.charAt(i)) == " "`.  And yeah, it'll never be true, cause a Character and a String aren't even the same type.

Comment: I've edited your post to restore the original and mention the changes you've made.  Please don't edit a question's original code after the fact, except to fix typos made during input; it invalidates answers.  Just add a note detailing what you've changed.  (But keep in mind, too, that the changes you made have morphed the question into a wholly different one.)

Comment: As for the problem now, it's logic-related.  `s.split(" ")` returns a `String[]`, and `words.length` returns an `int`.  The code you've added is in the wrong places; `getInputString()` should be *getting a string*, and `getWordCount` should be *getting a word count*.

Answer (score 3):

You have read the name of the method, and look at the comments to decide what should be implemented inside the method, and the values it should return.

The `getInputString` method signature should be:

```
private static String getInputString(Scanner s) {

    String inputString = "";

    // read the input string from system in
    // ....

    return inputString;

}
```

The `getWordCount` method signature should be:

```
private static int getWordCount(String input) {

    int wordCount = 0;

    // count the number of words in the input String
    // ...

    return wordCount;
}
```

The `main` method should look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // instantiate the Scanner variable

    // call the getInputString method to ... you guessed it ... get the input string

    // call the getWordCount method to get the word count

    // Display the word count
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
                 count=1 //last word must be counted
                 for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
                 {
                   ch=s.charAt(i);
                   if(ch==' ')
                   {
                     count++;
                   }
                 }
```

Comment: An explanation will be nice, also it's the same code as the op posted.

Answer (score 1):

Use `trim()` and `split()` on 1-n whitespace chars:

```
private static int getWordCount(String s) {
    return s.trim().split("\\s+").length;
}
```

The call to `trim()` is necessary, otherwise you'll get one extra "word" if there is leading spaces in the string.

The parameter `"\\s+"` is necessary to count multiple spaces as a single word separator. `\s` is the regex for "whitespace". `+` is regex for "1 or more".

Comment: First of all, this doesn't compile. Second of all, he is supposed to learn something.

Comment: @RosdiKasim oops! I copied the wrong method signature (fixed). Also, is he learning something now that I've added some explanation?

Comment: @RosdiKasim: Well he has tried something, that's why we answered

Comment: @Bohemian, I would have only redirect him to the relevant javadoc for each of the methods you use. Don't give him the fish, teach him how to fish ;-)

Comment: Furthermore, if you read the comment for his `getWordCount` method, he is supposed to count the words himself. Using built-in java methods doesn't count.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by :

```
private static int getWordCount(String input) {
    return input.split("\\s+").length;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to move the string from the first method to the getIntputString. And its giving me an error that its not applicable, and its being  constructed right. Then getting the int to go the method of getWordCount.  I can't get the code right to move to the next method.

Comment: I might suggest `"\\s+"` rather than `" "`.  Simply splitting on exactly each `\u0020` would almost certainly miscount the words in this comment, for example, cause i generally use two spaces after periods.  But the general idea is good.

Comment: [@user2509405](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2509405/user2509405) can you copy past exact error

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is, **count the number of spaces in the string**. That is the number of words in the string.

You will see your count will be off by 1, but after some pondering and bug hunting you will figure out why.

Happy learning!

Comment: Oops.  This comment has twenty-three spaces, if you view source.  But there are only twenty-one words.  Not every space separates words.

Comment: @cHao, Did you read the comment above his `getWordCount` method? **For this assignment you may assume that words will be separated by exactly one space.**

Comment: I didn't, actually.  I tend to subconsciously filter comments; they're all but invisible to me, unless they're pointed out, or they're excessive, or funny.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what trouble you're having with methods but I dont think you need more than one, try this: it uses split to split up the words in a string, and you can chose the delimeters

```
String sentence = "This is a sentence.";  
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");  

for (String word : words) {  
   System.out.println(word);  
}
```

then you can do:

```
numberOfWords = words.length();
```

if you want to use 3 methods, you can call a method from your `main()` method that does this for you, for example:

```
public String getInputString() {

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    if (s.length() > 0) {
        return s;
    } else {
        System.out.println("ERROR - string must not be empty.");
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        return getInputString();
    }
}

public int wordCount(String s) {

    words = splitString(s)

    return words.length();
}

public String[] splitString(String s) {

    return s.split(" ");
}
```

Comment: I can do it one method, but I have to use 3.

Comment: umm, in that case you can have one method for accepting the string, which passes to the wordcount method listed here, which calls a method that splits the string

Comment: @user2509405 there you go, i made 3 methods for you

Comment: hey this is what I have, and I in my second method it says that a String can't convert to a int.  here is my code.

Comment: @user2509405 I see your problem, read my code more closely, you put the wrong code in the wrong method

Comment: @user2509405  Your get word count should return words.length() and your getinput string should have the scanner code

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` method like :

```
String[] words = s.split("\\s+");
int wordCount = words.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code i think this is what you're trying to do:

```
private static int getWordCount(String input) {

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (input.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Here's what I've done:

- I've moved the code you were 'playing' with into the right method (`getWordCount`).
- Corrected the loop you were trying to use (I think you have for and while loops confused)
- Fixed your check for the space character (`' '` not `" "`)

There is a bug in this code which you'll need to work out how to fix:

- `getWordCount("How are you");` will return 2 when it should be 3
- `getWordCount("");` will return 0
- `getWordCount("Hello");` will return 0 when it should be 1

Good luck!

Comment: It would seem the code supplied in the question has been modified since I posted this

Comment: Yeah...for some reason, the code that would actually count words has been stripped out.  I was considering reverting.

Answer (score 0):

Better use simple function of spilt() with arguments as space

```
int n= str.split(" ").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int Repeat_Words(String arg1,String arg2)
{
    //It find number of words can be formed from a given string

    if(arg1.length() < 1 || arg2.length() < 1)
        return 0;

    int no_words = 99999;
    char[] str1 = arg1.toCharArray();
    char[] str2 = arg2.toCharArray();


    for(int x = 0; x < str1.length; x++)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        for(int y = 0; y < str2.length; y++)
        {
            if(str1[x] == str2[y])
            temp++;
        }
        if(temp == 0)
            return 0;
        if(no_words > temp)
            no_words = temp;

        temp = 0;
    }

    return no_words;
}
```